# milestone completion test class not getting 100% code coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, casemilestone

I have created the milestone completion trigger based on Salesforce's documentation (https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&language=en_US&type=0) however I am having difficulty in achieving code complete 100%

Adding a few Debug lines to the trigger, I have found that the SLAStartTime on my case is always null when this test class run.  Did I do something wrong on the case creation?  Checking the sandbox database for cases created normally and the SLAStartTime is always set to the case creation.

My Trigger after case update to close off resolution and first response milestone

```
trigger CompleteResolutionTimeMilestone on Case (after update) {
if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Standard'){
    DateTime completionDate = System.now(); 
        List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
        for (Case c : Trigger.new){
                if (((c.isClosed == true)||(c.Status == 'Closed'))&&    ((c.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&(c.SlaExitDate == null)))
                    updateCases.add(c.Id); {
                        system.debug('Case Id is: '+c.Id);
                        system.debug('Case isClosed: '+c.IsClosed);
                        system.debug('Case Status: '+c.Status);
                        system.debug('Case SLA Start Date: '+c.SlaStartDate);
                        system.debug('Case SLA Exit Date: '+c.SlaExitDate);
                        system.debug('Completion Date which is now: '+completionDate);}
    }

//Close off the Resolution Milestone and First Response milestone when case is closed
if (updateCases.isEmpty() == false) {
    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 'Resolution Time', completionDate);
    System.debug('Resolution Time'+completionDate );
    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 'First Response', completionDate);
    System.debug('First Response'+completionDate );}
}}
```

My Test Class

```
/**
* This is a test class for milestone test
* The milestone completion trigger is invoked after case update
*/
@isTest
private class TestCompleteMilestone {
    // test methods
    static testMethod void testCompleteMilestoneCase(){
        Account acc = new account(name='Test Account');
        insert acc;

    Contact oContact = new contact(firstname='John',lastname='Doe',email='test@test.com',accountid=acc.id);
    insert oContact;

    Entitlement entl = new entitlement(name='Test Entilement',accountid=acc.id,type='Gateway Support', StartDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addDays(-2)), EndDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addYears(2)));
    insert entl;

    String contactId;
    if (oContact != null)
        contactId = oContact.Id;

    String entlId;
    if (entl != null)
        entlId = entl.Id;

    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
    if (entlId != null){
        Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ', AccountId = acc.id, ContactId = oContact.id, EntitlementId=entl.id, slaStartDate=system.now());
        cases.add(c);
    }

    // Insert the Account records that cause the trigger to execute.
    if (cases.isEmpty()==false){
        insert cases;
        List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Case cL : cases){
            caseIds.add(cL.Id);
            system.debug('Case Entitlement:'+cL.entitlementid);
        }

        milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'First Response', System.now());
    }
}

static testMethod void testCompleteMilestoneViaCase(){

    // Perform data preparation
    Account acc = new account(name='Test Account');
    insert acc;

    Contact oContact = new contact(firstname='John',lastname='Doe',email='test@test.com',accountid=acc.id);
    insert oContact;

    Entitlement entl = new entitlement(name='Test Entilement',accountid=acc.id,type='Gateway Support', StartDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addDays(-2)), EndDate=Date.valueof(System.now().addYears(2)));
    insert entl;

    String entlId;
    if (entl != null)
        entlId = entl.Id;
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case ' + i);
        cases.add(c);
        if (entlId != null){
            c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ', AccountId = acc.id, ContactId = oContact.id, EntitlementId=entl.id, slaStartDate=system.now());
            cases.add(c);
        }
    }

    // Insert the Account records that cause the trigger to execute.
    insert cases;

    List<CaseComment> ccs = new List<CaseComment>{};
    for(Case c : cases){
        CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPublic', IsPublished=true, ParentId=c.Id);
        ccs.add(cc);
        cc = new CaseComment(CommentBody='TestPrivate', IsPublished=false, ParentId=c.Id);
        ccs.add(cc);
    }
    if (ccs.isEmpty()==false)
        insert ccs;

    // Now create emailmessage objects for them.
    List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
    for(Case c : cases){
        emails.add(new EmailMessage(parentId = c.id));
    }
    if(emails.isEmpty()==false)
        database.insert(emails);

    for(Case c : cases){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddr = new String[] {'mramsey@salesforce.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddr);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.ContactId);
        mail.setWhatId(c.Id);
        mail.setHtmlBody('TestHTMLBody');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('TestTextBody');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    for(Case c : cases){
      c.Status = 'Closed';
      c.AccountId = acc.id;
      c.Category__c = 'Other';
      c.Sub_Category__c = 'Other';
      c.Resolution__c = 'Other';
    }
    update cases;

    // Query the database for the newly inserted records.
    List<Case> insertedCases = [SELECT Subject,
                                       Description,
                                      (SELECT IsPublished, CommentBody From CaseComments),
                                      (SELECT TextBody, Subject, Incoming From EmailMessages)
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE Id IN :cases];
}}
```

Comment: What sets the value of slastarttime?

Comment: I thought the slastarttime is started automatically by the entitlement process.  It is a read only field and looks like a look up on case milestones.  Took the basic code from Salesforce documentation site (https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&language=en_US&type=0) and thought it should be 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Entitlement` record through your code without associating to an `Entitlement Process`. Also, make this `Entitlement Process` to `Active`.

Moreover, your test class might fail during deployment if you use organization data.

**Update**

> DML operation cannot be performed on SLAProcess Object (i.e. Entitlement Process).

So, you need to rely on organization data. Retrieve the entry from your organization and associate it to Entitlement.

```
List<SlaProcess> lstEntitlementProcess = [SELECT Id, Name FROM SlaProcess WHERE Name='<your Entitlement Process Name>' and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
    if (lstEntitlementProcess.size()>0)
    {
        entl.SlaProcessId = lstEntitlementProcess[0].id;
        update entl;        
    }
```

Ideally in this type of scenarios, it is advisable to prepare 2 changesets.
First Change set will contain all configuration components. Then after deploying that changeset, migrate or configure basic data (like define Entitlement Process if that doesn't exist in Production).

After that, in the 2nd changeset, deploy all class, pages, triggers. So it will not fail during deployment.

Comment: Thank you Santanu, I think that should be it as the trigger is working on normal process flow.  I will update the test class and associate the entitlement to entitlement process.  I think that is to do with slaprocess table.

Comment: Code complete with 100% now, edited the original post with the updated trigger and test class.

Comment: Hi Santanu,  sorry about it.  I have tried various ways to associate the entitlement record to the entitlement process but could not find a way.  Are you able to assist me in providing the code snippet to associate the Entitlement to Entittlement process?

Comment: Find the updated answer